# How to replace a word in a String?

Tags: java, string

I'm using a `String` like:

```
String message = "%%NAME is inviting you";
```

I am using `message.replaceAll("%%NAME", me);` where `me` is a `String`. This line of code is not working for me. I was wondering what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the code that you are using (that doesn't work)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Code looks more or less OK, though there may be some syntax issues. Here's a working example:

```
String message = "%%NAME is inviting you.";
String name = "Diana";
String result = message.replaceAll("%%NAME", name);
```

Comment: Oh, I thought you could just call the method and it would replace it. Thanks

Comment: @Sean Strings in Java are *immutable*: they can't change.  What martyman is doing here is creating a new string with %%NAME replaced.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest using the [`format` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead of `replaceAll` in this case.

### UPDATE - Example

```
String template = "%s is inviting you";
String name = "Bob";
String result = String.format(template, name);
```

Comment: +1: String.format is a good idea, assuming Sean is using Java >= 1.5.  Could you please also post an example?

Comment: The thing I like about this, is you can reuse the template numerous times. So you can use it with Bob, Mary, Peter, etc etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
String message = "%%name is inviting you";
String uname = "Keyser Sose";
message.replaceAll("%%name", uname);
```

...will not modify 'message' because Strings (in java) are immutable

```
String message = "%%name is inviting you";
String uname = "Keyser Sose";
message = message.replaceAll("%%name", uname);
```

..WILL work.  (Note the re-assignment of 'message')

Comment: if String in Java are immutable, then how the `message = message.replaceAll("%%name", uname);` replaces the `message` String object?

Comment: `message` is a pointer to a block of memory filled with a `String` object.  The contents of that block of memory is accessed via the `String` object's methods.  Since none of those methods allow for modification of any internal state, `String` is considered immutable.

The 'message.replaceAll("%%name", uname);' call returns a pointer to a new, different `String`, aka a different block of memory.

Thus the `message = message.replaceAll("%%name", uname);` line of code re-assigns which block of memory the `message` pointer is pointing at.

Comment: Thanks now I got it

Answer (score 3):

Rythm a java template engine now released with an new feature called **[String interpolation mode](http://www.playframework.org/modules/rythm-1.0.0-20120630/string_interpolation)** which allows you do something like:

```
String result = Rythm.render("@name is inviting you", "Diana");
```

The above case shows you can pass argument to template by position. Rythm also allows you to pass arguments by name:

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("title", "Mr.");
args.put("name", "John");
String result = Rythm.render("Hello @title @name", args);
```

Note Rythm is VERY FAST, about 2 to 3 times faster than String.format and velocity, because it compiles the template into java byte code, the runtime performance is very close to concatentation with StringBuilder.

Links:

- Check the [full featured demonstration](http://play-rythm-demo.appspot.com/)
- read [a brief introduction to Rythm](http://software-lgl.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/rythm-easy-to-use-high-performance-java.html)
- download the [latest package](https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm/downloads) or
- [fork it](https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm)

Answer (score 0):

To replace a string character with another string using StringUtil.Replace, I tried following and it's working fine for me to replace multiple string values from a single string.

String info = "[$FIRSTNAME$]*[$LASTNAME$]*[$EMAIL$]_[$ADDRESS$]";

String replacedString = StringUtil.replace(info, new String[] { "[$FIRSTNAME$]","[$LASTNAME$]","[$EMAIL$]","[$ADDRESS$]" }, new String[] { "XYZ", "ABC" ,"abc@abc.com" , "ABCD"});

This will replace the String value of info with newly provided value...